# Disabling automatic en dash when editing files in TextEdit

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, textedit

I've noticed that typying <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> in text edit results in those signs being converted to *en dash*: `–`. This is highly undesirable behaviour. For example correct formatting for the **SRT** files is (related [problem](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17543/12686)):

> time **-->** time

automatic *en dash* insertion is unnecessary here. Hence my question, how to disable it in TextEdit (the problem does not occur in Atom or TextWrangler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open TextEdit Preferences (⌘,) and uncheck **Smart dashes**.

You will need to close and re-open your documents for the change to take effect.